# Bitlocker stays at 99,9% encrypting a drive

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker

I'm trying to setup an external USB HD (2TB) with Bitlocker (Win10 21H2). Bitlocker stays at 99.9% when I try to encrypt the drive (just the "used data", not the whole drive).

It doesn't matter if the drive contains data or was just formatted. I tried to encrypt the whole drive but I cancelled the operation after 30min (it stayed at 0.1%).

Changing from "New encryption method" to "Compatible encryption method" does not make any difference as well.

Comment: thanks for the link, not sure why this didn't show up in my search

Comment: It actually showed up on the list of related questions while you were writing the question.